# How can I delete the empty row from a new DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wrote sample code for a DataGridView in C# and it has an empty row:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnEFz.png]

How can I delete the empty row on the left, so that my DataGridView looks like the one on the right, above?

Comment: Set `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` property to false.

Answer (score 0):

This Empty row appear because by default the `DataGridView` have enabled the property `[AllowUserToAddRows]` with a true value, set this property false and the row will disappear.